# rCharts with Highcharts as shiny application

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

I have a shiny application consisting of three files. server.R, ui.R and the file to launch the application with

```
require(shiny)
require(rCharts)
runApp("shinyApp")
```

The application starts, but the plot is not visible. It works with a normal r-plot and with polycharts, but after trying a lot, I still have no success with rCharts (which includes rHighcharts).

This is the files of the last try:

server.R:

```
library(rCharts)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$myChart <- renderChart({
    h1 <- Highcharts$new()
    h1$chart(type = "spline")
    h1$series(data = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5), dashStyle = "longdash")
    h1$series(data = c(NA, 4, 1, 3, 4), dashStyle = "shortdot")
    h1$legend(symbolWidth = 80)
    return(h1)
  })
})
```

ui.R:

```
require(rCharts)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("rCharts: Highcharts"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "x",
      label = "Choose X",
      choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
      selected = "SepalLength")
    ),
  mainPanel(showOutput("myChart", "Highcharts")
  )
))
```

My assumption is that the second argument of "showOutput" might be wrong, but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two ways to get this working. The first way is to add `h1$set(dom = "myChart")` in your `server.R`. This is required so that both `server.R` and `ui.R` are communicating about the correct chart. The alternative is to use `renderChart2`, which is in the `dev` branch of `rCharts`, that is a upgraded version of `renderChart` and will eventually replace it. I am attaching the entire code for everyone's benefit.

```
require(rCharts)
require(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui =  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("rCharts: Highcharts"),
    sidebarPanel(selectInput(
      inputId = "x",
      label = "Choose X",
      choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
      selected = "SepalLength"
    )),
    mainPanel(showOutput("myChart", "Highcharts"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$myChart <- renderChart2({
      h1 <- Highcharts$new()
      h1$chart(type = "spline")
      h1$series(data = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5), dashStyle = "longdash")
      h1$series(data = c(NA, 4, 1, 3, 4), dashStyle = "shortdot")
      h1$legend(symbolWidth = 80)
      return(h1)
    })
  }
))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the fact that `rcharts` is `javascript` based on there are strong incompatibilities between `R` variable names and `javascript` allowed variable names. Specifically with regards to dots `.` in names.

Try running the following function on the `data.frame` names and any `character` columns:

```
noDot <- function(x)
   gsub("\\.", "_", gsub("^\\.", "", x) )
```

ie:

```
names(df) <- noDot(names(df))
# and
char.cols <- sapply(df, function(x) any(is(x)=="character"))
df[, char.cols] <- sapply(df[, char.cols], noDot)
# note that this has not been tested
```