# rCharts highlight charts in shiny not working

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny, rcharts

Using the answer to an existing question as a base for reproducible code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19127732/1199712)

I get the following error, and am unsure why it does not work...It seems to be a generic problem when rendering `hPlot` type charts in shiny, as I constantly keep getting the same error

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7537
Error in normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE) : 
  path[1]="": No such file or directory


Error in normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE) : 
  path[1]="": No such file or directory
> traceback()
21: normalizePath(directoryPath, mustWork = TRUE)
20: addResourcePath(LIB$name, LIB$url)
19: singleton(addResourcePath(LIB$name, LIB$url))
18: withCallingHandlers(expr, message = function(c) invokeRestart("muffleMessage"))
17: suppressMessages(singleton(addResourcePath(LIB$name, LIB$url)))
16: showOutput("myChart", "Highcharts")
15: tag("div", list(...))
14: tags$div(...)
13: div(class = paste0("col-sm-", width), ...)
12: mainPanel(showOutput("myChart", "Highcharts"))
11: tag("div", list(...))
10: tags$div(...)
9: div(class = "row", sidebarPanel, mainPanel)
8: tag("div", list(...))
7: tags$div(...)
6: div(class = "container-fluid", div(class = "row", headerPanel), 
       div(class = "row", sidebarPanel, mainPanel))
5: tagList(if (!is.null(title)) tags$head(tags$title(title)), if (!is.null(theme)) {
  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", 
                      href = theme))
}, list(...))
4: attachDependencies(tagList(if (!is.null(title)) tags$head(tags$title(title)), 
                              if (!is.null(theme)) {
                                tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", 
                                                    href = theme))
                              }, list(...)), importBootstrap())
3: bootstrapPage(div(class = "container-fluid", div(class = "row", 
                                                    headerPanel), div(class = "row", sidebarPanel, mainPanel)))
2: pageWithSidebar(headerPanel("rCharts: Highcharts"), sidebarPanel(selectInput(inputId = "x", 
                                                                                label = "Choose X", choices = c("SepalLength", "SepalWidth", 
                                                                                                                "PetalLength", "PetalWidth"), selected = "SepalLength")), 
                   mainPanel(showOutput("myChart", "Highcharts")))
1: runApp(list(ui = pageWithSidebar(headerPanel("rCharts: Highcharts"), 
                                    sidebarPanel(selectInput(inputId = "x", label = "Choose X", 
                                                             choices = c("SepalLength", "SepalWidth", "PetalLength", 
                                                                         "PetalWidth"), selected = "SepalLength")), mainPanel(showOutput("myChart", 
                                                                                                                                         "Highcharts"))), server = function(input, output) {
                                                                                                                                           output$myChart <- renderChart2({
                                                                                                                                             h1 <- Highcharts$new()
                                                                                                                                             h1$chart(type = "spline")
                                                                                                                                             h1$series(data = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5), dashStyle = "longdash")
                                                                                                                                             h1$series(data = c(NA, 4, 1, 3, 4), dashStyle = "shortdot")
                                                                                                                                             h1$legend(symbolWidth = 80)
                                                                                                                                             return(h1)
                                                                                                                                           })
                                                                                                                                         }))
```

below is my sessionInfo after an upgrade in rCharts...which resulted in the same error...also note that highlight charts work locally when viewing in RStudio's viewer, but not in shiny when using the `showOutput` function

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: powerpc64le-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shiny_0.11.1  rCharts_0.4.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] codetools_0.2-8 digest_0.6.8    grid_3.1.1      htmltools_0.2.6
 [5] httpuv_1.3.2    lattice_0.20-29 mime_0.3        nabor_0.4.4    
 [9] plyr_1.8.1      R6_2.0.1        Rcpp_0.11.5     RJSONIO_1.3-0  
[13] tools_3.1.1     whisker_0.3-2   xtable_1.7-4    yaml_2.1.13
```

Comment: try with `output$myChart <- renderChart({
      h1 <- Highcharts$new()
      h1$set(dom = "myChart")
    
    })`

Comment: also u need to install dev version of rcharts install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv',ref='dev')

Comment: delete and reinstall rshiny and rcharts (you might need to reinstall other dependencies also)

Answer (score 1):

Changing `"Highcharts"` to `"highcharts"` inside `showOutput()` fixes it for me (using rCharts version 0.4.5):

```
require(rCharts)
require(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui =  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("rCharts: Highcharts"),
    sidebarPanel(selectInput(
      inputId = "x",
      label = "Choose X",
      choices = c('SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth'),
      selected = "SepalLength"
    )),
    mainPanel(showOutput("myChart", "highcharts"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output){
    output$myChart <- renderChart2({
      h1 <- Highcharts$new()
      h1$chart(type = "spline")
      h1$series(data = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5), dashStyle = "longdash")
      h1$series(data = c(NA, 4, 1, 3, 4), dashStyle = "shortdot")
      h1$legend(symbolWidth = 80)
      return(h1)
    })
  }
))
```