# R, Shiny can not do rChart

Tags: r, shiny

Are there any restrictions on using `hPlot` (vs `hist`) in shiny? I could not find any info about restrictions on using rCharts stuff on shiny. Not sure what I'm missing.

I really need/want to use hPlot to make better presentation.

```
## ui.R
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Count Report "),
    h4("This application shows product data"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectizeInput("product","Product:",c("ALPHA","BRAVO","all"), selected="all")
        ),

        mainPanel(
          h4("rChart Auuuuu??????!!!"),
          plotOutput("chart")

        )
    )
))


##---server.R
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

shinyServer(
    function(input, output) {
      x <- data.frame(Category=factor(c("ALPHA", "ALPHA","BRAVO","ALPHA","ALPHA")), 
                      YYYYMM= factor(c("2/1/2015","3/1/2015","4/1/2015","5/1/2015","6/1/2015")),
                      COUNT=c(44,22,37,76,97))

        output$chart <- renderPlot({
          # generate an rnorm distribution and plot it
          #hist(x$COUNT)    ######### this works OK
          hPlot(COUNT ~ YYYYMM, data=x, type="line") ######### doesnt WORK!
        })
})
```

Comment: What's going wrong? "Doesn't work" isn't helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rCharts with Highcharts as shiny application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121695/rcharts-with-highcharts-as-shiny-application)

Comment: plot is not displayed on html, but page comes out

Comment: I checked another post,  with renderChart2, it works but for not for my hPlot. I still don't have any plot output in main panel, but page comes out OK

Comment: The rCharts website explains how to do it: http://ramnathv.github.io/rChartsShiny/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note the changes I made where I used `showOutput` instead of `plotOutput` and  `renderChart2` instead of `renderPlot` as you need to make* these changes to make `rChart` plots. Also you need to specify namespace in the `showOutput`, I ***think*** that `hplot` belongs to `highcharts` but I might be wrong *(if anyone knows for sure feel free to comment here so I can update the answer)*. For more information about using `rCharts` you can look at the examples [here on github](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/blob/master/inst/libraries/highcharts/examples.R).

The following should work:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Count Report "),
  h4("This application shows product data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("product","Product:",c("ALPHA","BRAVO","all"), selected="all")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h4("rChart works!"),
      showOutput("chart", "highcharts")

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  x <- data.frame(Category=factor(c("ALPHA", "ALPHA","BRAVO","ALPHA","ALPHA")), 
                  YYYYMM= factor(c("2/1/2015","3/1/2015","4/1/2015","5/1/2015","6/1/2015")),
                  COUNT=c(44,22,37,76,97))

  output$chart <- renderChart2({
    a <- hPlot(COUNT ~ YYYYMM, data=x, type="line") ######### doesnt WORK!
    return (a)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks much Pork Chop!  It works , now I'm trying to plug in reactive() things into it.